# Working out date from ISO-8601 Period in Bash Script

Tags: python, bash, shell, datetime

I have a few ISO-8601 Period dates such as:

> a) P7M2D
>
> b) P142D

(a = 7Months 2 Days ago) (b = 142 Days ago)

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way using a bash script (shell) to see if I can work out the date from that. If **today is let's say 25 October 2019**, then the answer would be:

**a** would be: 23 March 2019

**b** would be: 5 June 2019

Ideally it should print date in yyyy/mm/dd format.

```
$> ./script.sh P7M2D
   2019/03/23

$> ./script.sh P142D
   2019/06/05
```

Wonder if this is easier to do in Python, feel free to give an example in Python but I'm not too familiar with Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *almost* do this with plain bash: bash's `printf` has a `%(date_format)T` formatter to strftime a date given a time value, but bash doesn't have any way to *parse* a datetime string.

This version depends on GNU date:

```sh
period_ago() {
    if [[ $1 =~ ^P(([0-9]+)M)?([0-9]+)D$ ]]; then
        local months=${BASH_REMATCH[2]:-0}
        local days=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
        date -d "now - $months months - $days days" "+%Y/%m/%d"
    fi
}
```

then

```
$ period_ago P142D
2019/06/05
$ period_ago P7M2D
2020/05/23
```

A quick look through the Python docs gives me the feeling that this will be difficult to do in Python: the timedelta doesn't provide a "months" field (after all, how many days are in 7 months?)

But Perl's [DateTime module](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) (which you'd have to install) can do it:

```sh
period_ago_perl() {
    perl -MDateTime -E '
        my $period = shift @ARGV;
        if ($period =~ /^P(?:(\d+)M)?(\d+)D/) {
            say DateTime->now()
                ->subtract(months => ($1 || 0), days => $2)
                ->strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
        }
    ' "$1"
}
```

```
$ period_ago_perl P7M2D
2019/03/23
$ period_ago_perl P142D
2019/06/05
```

Comment: Looks great but how can I call this function within the bash script from a terminal command line, I get nothing with: ./script.sh && period_ago P142D

Comment: What is in script.sh?

Comment: I mean, I want to store the function "period_ago" in a shell script file called script.sh so I can invoke/call it, but s'okay I will figure it out. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Add that function to your `~/.bashrc` and then `source ~/.bashrc` -- then you can call it from the command line just as I showed. Change the name to something more memorable for you if you want.

Comment: I just realised that if I use P1M0D, it ADDs the date to current date, rather than SUBTRACT. Apart from that, your bash version script works perfectly. :)

Comment: That's with the `date` command right? The "ago" must not be interpreted correctly with "0 days". Try `"now - $months months - $days days" `